# Which URL to use for the Fedora EPEL repo mirrorlist in a kickstart config?

Tags: centos, fedora, repository, kickstart

I am writing a kickstart file to configure a CentOS 7 installation. I'd like to install some packages from the Fedora EPEL repository, so I'm adding a `repo` command to the configuration.

I'm having trouble finding the canonical URL I should use for the `--mirrorlist` option. Where would this be documented?

```
repo --name=epel --mirrorlist=<which url?>
%packages
# various packages
%end
```

I didn't see anything listed in the [EPEL FAQ](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ) and Fedora's [mirror manager](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/mirrormanager/) site just has a bunch of human-readable pages. In addition, the [kickstart documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/sect-kickstart-syntax.html) does not document what the format of a mirror list must be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fedora Project has some documentation on its mirrorlists on its [MirrorManage wiki page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Infrastructure/MirrorManager).

> `metalink=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-10&arch=$basearch`
>
> `mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=fedora-10&arch=$basearch`

I also discovered that the CentOS 7 `epel-release` package installs a configuration file at `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` which had some clues:

```
[epel]
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=$basearch
```

[Anaconda supports](https://github.com/rhinstaller/pykickstart/blob/master/docs/kickstart-docs.rst) substituting `$basearch` and other variables in a kickstart `repo` command.

Ultimately I had a lot of trouble with `repo` commands and was not able to install the `epel-release` package from kickstart. I gave up and used Packer and Ansible to install packages instead.

Comment: @Christopher Which as you can see, is rather empty... just a link to http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

```
https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-7&arch=x86_64
```

This is just [a plain text file](https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-7&arch=x86_64), with one URL per line.

By providing [invalid entries](https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=foo&arch=bar) for the `repo` and `arch` parameters, you can get a list of valid entries, including:

```
# repo=epel-6&arch=i386
# repo=epel-6&arch=ppc64
# repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64
# repo=epel-7&arch=aarch64
# repo=epel-7&arch=ppc64
# repo=epel-7&arch=ppc64le
# repo=epel-7&arch=x86_64
```